# Why can't I put a borrowed value behind a Mutex and pass it to another thread?

Tags: rust, mutex

I'm trying to put a borrowed value behind a `Mutex` but I'm having trouble with the borrow checker. Here's a simplified code that demonstrate the problem I encounter:

```rust
use std::{
    marker::PhantomData,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

struct Test<'a> {
    d: PhantomData<Mutex<&'a u8>>,
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Test { d: PhantomData }
    }
    pub fn test(&'a self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let t = Arc::new(Test::new());
    let t2 = t.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        t2.test();
    });
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error

```
error[E0597]: `t2` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:9
   |
19 |     let t2 = t.clone();
   |         -- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `t2`
20 |     std::thread::spawn(move || {
21 |         t2.test();
   |         ^^-------
   |         |
   |         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `t2` is borrowed for `'1`
22 |     });
   |     - `t2` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I guess the compiler thinks `t2` might be borrowed to somewhere else when calling `test()`. It seems if I modify the type of the `d` field in `struct Test` to anything excluding `Mutex`, such as `d: Option<&'a u8>`, it works fine. What is so special about Mutex since it's just a wrapper around an `UnsafeCell`?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates — wrapping a reference in a mutex doesn't change the fact that the referred-to-value may stop existing before the reference is used. You probably want to use _scoped threads_.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i still don't understand why there's no error if I _don't_ use mutex and instead use a reference directly or wrap it with somthing other than mutex, in this case the referenced value could also be dropped before used.

Comment: In that case [`'a` is inferred as `'static`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c0f238baabef60185937c4ea819c900) which is fine to pass between threads.

Comment: Oh i see. But mutex still cause the error even if I [explicitly take 'a to be 'static](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9377febaa742efc03206d41c1a6b022)

Comment: You also have `fn test(&'a self) {}` which is nonsense the vast majority of the time. That means that the instance that the method is called on has to live as long as `'a`. When you set it to `'static`, your instance doesn't live that long.

Comment: But my instance is behind an Arc so it should live as `'static`? There's also no error if I [remove the mutex](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abb518adadacc71c5cd6ece0395b7d3f)

Comment: No, the `Arc` lives until it is dropped, it is not a `static` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is so special about Mutex since it's just a wrapper around an `UnsafeCell`?

The difference is [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

`&'a T` is **covariant** in the lifetime `'a`: You can coerce an immutable reference with a longer lifetime to one with a strictly shorter lifetime, because it is always safe to pass `&'long T` where `&'short T` is expected.  This is why the code compiles without the `UnsafeCell`.

But `UnsafeCell<&'a T>` is **invariant** in `'a` because it has interior mutability: If you could pass `UnsafeCell<&'long T>` to code that takes `UnsafeCell<&'short T>`, that code could write a short-lived reference into your long-lived cell.  So it is not safe to coerce an `UnsafeCell` to have a different lifetime.

(The same is true for any type that lets you mutate the reference it contains, e.g. `Mutex<&'a T>` or `&mut &'a T`.)